# Writing .htm file name to the contents of the file in HTML

Tags: javascript, html, filenames

E.g. I have a file named: page1.htm

In the HTML I need to show a link for Google result of a search for that file name. I.e.:

https://www.google.co.uk/?gfe_rd=cr&ei=6MhcVOGVHMnH8gej8oCQDQ&gws_rd=ssl#q=page1

Obviously if I need to do this for lots of pages, it would be easier if there was a way to amend the end of that search string to depend on the filename (without the extension).

Please tell me there is a simple way to produce that result!

Thanks

Comment: What can I use then, I can just about deal with .js, although I have been trying to avoid where possible. Can I just call a .js file at the end of that string, that amends the link on opening?

Comment: If i understand your question, you can not do this only with HTML.

Comment: So how can I code this using .js?

Comment: Just to add one detail: This can also be accomplished with a server-side language like PHP, if the server you're running supports it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are serving a static html page, any 'active' behavior, (like automatically reusing the file's name in the content) will need to happen at runtime on the client side. That means Javascript:

```
<!-- In your html, use an ID tag to make the link easily selectable with javascript...--> 
<a id="googleSearchLink" href="#">Search Google for the name of this file</a>
```

Then at the bottom of the body content (so that it happens after the  tag is rendered) add:

```
<script>
  // Grab everything after the last "/" from the location bar...
  var filename = window.location.href.substr(window.location.href.lastIndexOf("/")+1);

  // Chop off the last "." and everything right of it...
  var withoutExtension = filename.replace(/\.[^/.]+$/, "");

  // Build the link destination as a string...
  var hrefTargetForGoogleLink = "https://www.google.co.uk/#q=" + withoutExtension;

  // Finally, set the link destination
  googleSearchLink.href = hrefTargetForGoogleLink;    

</script>
```

Comment: Thanks, would you know how to use the filename within a <frame>? <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d638.2749352951106!2d-5.282082938430027!3d50.21535656989126!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x486b20111d678ba9%3A0xf879a4f9a3bf7649!2s(((HERE)))%2C+UK!5e0!3m2!1sen!2s!4v1411384484901" width="400" height="300" frameborder="0" style="border:0"></iframe>

Comment: hoverbikers answered to your question. If it does what you need, accept his answer, and create a new question for your new problem.